# How to move my animation on simplegui specifically

Tags: python, animation, project, simplegui

Ok so I am doing this animation that there are 4 circles and I want them to start from the lines I have put and i want it to hit the next line and come back to the 1st line but how can I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```py
import simplegui

x = -100

def draw_handler(canvas):
    global x

    for i in range(2, 5):
        #global x
        x = x + 1
        
        canvas.draw_circle((x, 200), 50, 1, "red", "orange")
        
        canvas.draw_circle((x, 420), 50, 1, "green", "green")
        
    for i in range(0, 2):
        
        x = x + 1
        canvas.draw_circle((321, x), 30, 1, "blue", "blue")
    if x > 650:
         x = -50
    if x > 500:
          x = -100
        
 
   
    canvas.draw_line([500, 100], [500, 450], 20, "green")
    canvas.draw_line([50, 500], [500, 500], 20, "blue")
    canvas.draw_line([500, 50], [50, 45], 20, "red")
    canvas.draw_line([50, 100], [50, 450], 20, "yellow")
  
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Animation", 700, 700)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using